# How to keep user input in input box? [HTML/AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can one keep a user's input in an input box?

This is what I have so far:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userText" placeholder="Enter text here">
```

But I want it so that when the user is done typing, it keeps the text there. How would I do this?

Comment: You want this to persist through reloads or just when, say, a submit button is pressed?

Comment: `placeholder` text is _supposed_ to disappear once the user starts inputting text. Unclear what you are asking – what do you actually mean by “keeping the text there”? Do you want the user to add their own input to your given text (so it becomes kind of a “prefix”), do you want it to be displayed below the text the user inputs, or – what?

Comment: I want it to stay the same through reloads.

I don't want to keep the placeholder, I want to keep the text the user inputted into the input box.

@RichardKho

Comment: _“I want it to stay the same through reloads”_ – then you have to read it and store it somewhere, so that you can put it into the input field again after the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.value = sessionStorage.getItem('input-value') || '';
inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('input-value', inp.value)
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1z5ovbhn/)